# Prevent all the properties on one line for multi-line objects using Eslint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Using Eslint, I want to allow either the entire object on 1 line or the braces + each property on separate line, i.e.:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2 };

{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
};
```

However, Eslint's auto-fix is producing and allowing this:

```
{
  a: 1, b: 2,
};
```

Is there a rule to prevent this?

The relevant rules I'm using are:

```
'object-curly-newline': [2, {
  minProperties: 4,
  consistent: true,
}],
'object-property-newline': [2, { allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine: true }],
```

Comment: Which rule are you using that creates this autofix?

Comment: `object-curly-newline` and `object-property-newline` are the rules you should look at. I've had to fork the `array` counterparts for some missing features, but those for objects should allow all the variations.

Comment: @Bergi oops forgot to add my config. I just added `minProperties: 4` today and ran `--fix`